# Script to send email to specific cell within a column every time the cell next to it gets updated

Tags: google-sheets

I hope this haven't been asked before I'm trying to do what the title says.

In this particular example I got email list on column A, and I want that email address to receive a notification when the cell next to it gets updates to "Yes"

So far I got this:

```
function Initialize() {

  var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();

  for(var i in triggers) {
    ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
  }

  ScriptApp.newTrigger("sendNotification")
  .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet())
  .onEdit()
  .create();

};


/**
 * 
 */


function sendNotification(e) {


  if("B2" == e.range.getA1Notation() ) {

    if(e.value == "Yes") {



      var recipients = "IDK what to put in here";
      var subject = "There's an update to your request";
      var body = "We resolved your issue!";


      MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have edited the code with comments to explain what I changed, you were on the right track. OnEditTriggers to send Email is usually frowned upon, generally not a good practice. However, in your case you still have control on when to send an email, so improvement over just flat out emailing on every Edit.

FYI you dont need Initialize() to setup the manual triggers you can set it up manually: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually

```
 function Initialize() {
      var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
      // The below code would delete all the triggers in your project not just the one you setup through this code.  
      for(var i in triggers) {
        ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
      }
      ScriptApp.newTrigger("sendNotification")
       .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet())
       .onEdit()
       .create();
      };

   function sendNotification(e) {
      //if("B2" == e.range.getA1Notation() ) {
      //This will only check is the range is B2 cell, if you want to check for  column B. use getColumn
      if(e.range.getColumn() == 2){
        if(e.value == "Yes") {   
          //var recipients = "xxx@gmail.com"; //Email Address of the indented Recipents 
          // In your case email would be the value in cell A2 or cell in Column A corresponding to the one edited in Col B
          // you can get that value like so
          var recipients = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.getRow(),1).getValue()
          Logger.log(recipients)
          var subject = "There's an update to your request";
          var body = "We resolved your issue!";
          MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body);
        }
      }
    }
```

New functions:

**e.range.getColumn()/getRow()** to get the specific column or row. So that way you working with numbers and not string. Easy to manipulate numbers with arithmetic compared to strings.

**e.source.getActiveSheet()** gives you sheet object of where the change happened. You use e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() to get the name of the sheet and use it to make sure email is only fired when an edit happens on a specific sheet.

Comment: I finally made it work, I made some modifications to ir so it can work with some sheets I was working on, but thanks a lot! I was going nuts not knowing how to properly use e.range.getColumn/Row

Comment: Glad I could help